# Postgres statistic gathering

Tags: database, postgresql

Statistics can be turned off for specific columns on a table. Can someone point me to the pg table that tells me which columns of a relation are not having stats gathered on? I have already looked at pg_stats and pg_statistics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [pg_attribute](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html), you need the column attstattarget to see the status.